# problema al subir archivo con ftp_put()

Tags: javascript, php, html, formularios, ftp

al utilizar función `ftp_put()` de php para cargar archivo a un ftp, efectivamente sube el archivo, pero llega sin peso alguno, osea 0 B, adjunto el código que estoy utilizando(no es problema de permisos de la carpeta a donde lo estoy enviando, el archivo llega de un formulario y lo recojo en el php)

```
$c = ftp_connect('miftp.com') or die("error al conectar");
ftp_login($c, 'miuser', 'pass') or die("no logueo");
$fichero = fopen($_FILES['sArchivo']['name'];

$remote = "/carpeta/".$_FILES['sArchivo']['name'];
ftp_put($c, $remote, $fichero ,  FTP_bynary) or die("Can't transfer");
```

este es el formulario :

```
<form action="../ajax/producto-checkfile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>   
        <label for="upload">Selecciona un fichero</label>
        <input name="sArchivo" type="file" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" />    
   </div>   
</form>
```

Comment: Intenta enviar el archivo a otra ubicación en tu mismo equipo y en esta prueba no uses FTP, es posible que no estés leyendo el archivo y/o el archivo no tenga datos. ¿has verificado si el archivo que estás generando efectivamente tiene datos?, solo estarías creando un archivo vacío con un nombre y extensión, pero sin datos.

Comment: Efectivamente ya hice esa prueba solo con `move_uploaded_file`, lo envía a la carpeta que coloco y con datos, estoy estancado en el punto del `ftp_put()`, de hecho ya intente con la librería cURL y con este ni siquiera lo envía... no entiendo por qué con `ftp_put()` lo envía vació, he buscado documentación y según veo es muy fácil, pero a mi no me funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Por equivocación omití la función `ftp_pasv()`, lo coloqué `true` porque las conexiones de datos son iniciadas por el cliente, y listo.